# Ethernet and wifi not working properly if both are enabled on RPI5

Tags: wifi, ethernet, pi-5

Scenario one: Wifi turned on connected to router, 5Gz channel 36 range approx 1m. SSH works as expected from ethernet wired pc to pi, but wifi is slower than expected, at 10MB/s. Powershell/Putty/winscp all work

Scenario two: same as above but wifi is connected to wifi from ACCESS POINT, which in turn is connected to router via ethernet. Can ssh in, but some commands cause the ssh link to crash, while others don't. The behavior is very repeatable. For example, ifconfig is reliable, but "top" causes a crash immediately every time. dmesg prints 15-20 lines before crashing the link. The pi itself does not crash, as a second terminal stays alive and working. Putty/winSCP do not work at all, while powershell works as above.

Scenario three: Wifi is connected to router, and ethernet is connected through a simple switch to the router. Both ethernet and wifi link behave as in scenario 2, with some commands working, some not, winSCP/putty dont work at all. If at boot the wifi is the only link up, wifi works as in scenario one. However, if I subsequently enable ethernet, BOTH links behave as in scenario 2.

Behavior is the same on both headless Raspberry Pi OS* and ubuntu headless

Is there something strange going on here? Am I doing something stupid? Have I got a defective pi? Any help much appreciated!

Edit: All I did to configure the ethernet was the following:

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.xxx/24 dev eth0
ip link set dev eth0 up
```

Comment: "Is there something strange going on here? Am I doing something stupid? Have I got a defective pi?" You haven't explained WHAT YOU DID or listed any diagnostics. You don't enhance your creditability by claiming to use "rasbian"(sic); Raspbian is a 32 bit OS and won't run on a Pi5

Comment: First - don't worry, most of us know what you mean by raspbian/rasbian. Second - I'm curious about this passage in your Q: _"... 5Gz channel 36 range approx 1m."_ Is that 1m as in `1 meter` of range? And finally a suggestion: Your RPi5 uses `NetworkManager` to configure networking & net devices. You should read [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/network-manager) to learn a bit about `nmcli` and `NetworkManager`. Run some of these commands on your system, then edit your question to add the commands & output you got that you aren't clear on.

Comment: @Seamus Yes, 1 meter. I am running ubuntu currently which doesn't seem to use network manager by default. Which information specifically are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

##### Q: *"Is there something strange going on here?"*

##### A: Possibly, but you've not given us enough information to help you.

Your RPi5 network configuration is controlled by `NetworkManager`, and set up in accordance with input you provided when you created the image on your SD card using the **Raspberry Pi Imager**.

**If** you have done **nothing** to attempt to configure networking on your RPi5, it should work with either wifi - or Ethernet - or both. If you have done **something** to attempt to configure your network, that may be the source of your problem. In either case, you need to edit your question to communicate (first) whether or not you've done **something** to configure your network, and if so what did you do?

This is as much of an answer as I can give until you answer these questions. Troubleshooting network issues is a **process**, and it must begin with a disclosure of how the network is currently configured. So - edit your question, and we'll go from there.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect but frankly I did nothing that should cause this